# I have an error with ajax query CODEIGNITER

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have this error in my developer console :

```
(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.sigere.site/login/makeLogin?user=admin&pass=123456' from origin 'https://sigere.site' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am doing a simple LOGIN and redirect to other page in codeigniter 
that is my ajax query

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url+'login/makeLogin',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            beforeSend:function(){
            },
            success:function(r){
                if(r.response==2){
                    window.location.replace(base_url+'Admin');
                }
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, msg){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        });
```

and my function in the controller is

```
public function index() { 
        $this->load->view('registro');
    }
```

Comment: did you try with post method?

Comment: Yes, but dont work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try allowing

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");
```

or adding this in htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```